# Pyramid is slow with big in-memory object

Tags: python, pyramid

In the Pyramid web framework in `__init__.py`  I put a 100 MB object into settings.  In `views.py` I scan that object.  But it's so slow.  I put prints in my view, and my scan is fast ... the delay is BEFORE my view gets called.  Pyramid takes about 5 seconds before my view ever gets called.  Is Pyramid copying the settings?  Is there a better way to pass an in-memory object from `__init__` to `views`?

Edit:

In `__init__.py main(global_config, **settings)` I have:

```
settings['db_info'] = huge_dictionary
```

and in views.py I have:

```
db_info = request.registry.settings['db_info']
```

Judging by the performance, it must be copying the entire huge_dictionary.
One way around it is to cPickle the huge object to disk, then read it back in the view.
It just seems there should be a way to keep the object in main memory.

More Edit:
Thanks you Michael Merickel!  It looks like Pyramid is indeed copying the settings on every view dispatch.
The way my tests show it, Pyramid is doing a deep copy, not shallow.  All of the following show the
same very slow time:

```
settings['db_info'] = big_data
settings['db_info'] = [big_data]
settings['db_info'] = {'aa' : [big_data]}
```

But using cPickle works quickly!

Comment: I believe this is because you're using the debug toolbar which does serialize the **`settings`**  for each view. Just do not stuff your data into the `settings` but use the `registry` for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pyramid does do an initial copy of the dict that you pass into the configurator, but it is a shallow copy. If you are really passing 100mb dict to the configurator, then just pass it as a key of a parent dict instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an event subscriber for the `ApplicationCreated` event, and load your data after the creation of the wsgi (but before any requests are processed).  If your data is not required to configure the app (ie some `include` is not expecting it), this might be a good fit.

Also, I chose to store the data as a registry key rather than setting.  Dividing configuration data from data that the application needs to run is a nice separation of concerns that the map like registry object makes possible.

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

def appcreated(event):
    reg = event.app.registry
    reg['bigdata'] = reg['dataloader'](reg.settings)


def loader(settings):
    return "THE ENORMOUS GIGANTIC DATA"


def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.add_subscriber(appcreated, 'pyramid.events.ApplicationCreated')
    config.registry['loader'] = loader
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```